# Is this safe? Wiring for power relay jqc-3fc(t73)dc5v

Tags: relay, safety

I have an ac relay jqc-3fc(t73)dc5v that I am trying to use with a atmega and drive with 5v. Is the wiring as shown in the picture a good idea? Considering that ac and DC need to be very close together on the pins? The brass thing will be carrying 220 v ac. The jumpers carry DC. The relay will drive the pump as shown in the picture. The wooden box will be used to contain the relay and ac lines.
[image: relay image][image: wiring].[image: the relay will drive this][image]

Comment: I really don't like that big brass thing exposed with 240 V.  I suggest using one of the "Arduino" relay modules - a relay mounted on a small PC board with screw terminal blocks, and an optoisolator for the control input.  That will have much safer connections on the AC side.

Comment: I agree - I would solder a wire to the relay and insulate with heat-shrink tubing, then put the other end of the wire in the brass thing, ideally located in a plastic box so that it can't be touched.